# Insert data into DbContext saveChanges exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to add a bulk of data in my `DbContext` (SQLite DB).
What I want is to add x amount of data, and if some of them already exist, ignore those. So for example: add 100, 2 already exist, 98 items are added.

First I did a insert of all of them and then call `saveChanges()`, but that reverted the insert of all of them. Therefore I changed it to `saveChanges()` in the for-loop but I'm experiencing the same problem.

Do I need to clear something after an exception?

```
public int Insert(List<Car> Cars)
{            
    int addedCars = 0;
    foreach (Car t in Cars)
    {
        _db.Cars.Add(t);
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
            addedCars++;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Whups duplicate entry");
        }
    }
    return addedCars;
}
```

Comment: What is the logic to check the dupes? By ID or just object equality?

Comment: @marc_s: If I add x items, and some of them already exist in the database, I don't want those added. I was hoping I could rely on the DB logic and simply throw an error and continue with the rest.

Comment: @sza: the Object has 7 keys, and 6 of them are used as primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to remove it from the context. You're receiving an exception, but the entity is still "added" to the context. So the next time you SaveChanges(), you'll get the same exception.

### Option 1:

```
public int Insert(List<Car> Cars)
{            
    int addedCars = 0;
    foreach (Car t in Cars)
    {
        _db.Cars.Add(t);
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
            addedCars++;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            _db.cars.Remove(t); // Remove it from the context collection
            Console.WriteLine("Whups duplicate entry");
        }
    }
    return addedCars;
}
```

### Option 2 (preferred):

I really suggest you not even attempt to add the entities if they already exist.

You could do this before your add logic:

```
Cars = Cars.Where(x => !_db.Cars.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID)).ToList();
```

**Note** that even though this technically "checks" 100 records, it is doing so in memory with a single SQL statement. This is much faster than inserting even a few records erroneously.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just test if the item already exists before adding it?

```
if(!_db.Cars.Any(c => c == t))
{
   _db.Cars.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: Well obvious this is duable, but that means there will be 100 checks, and then 98 insert (198 operations). Isn't it better to have 100 operactions and rely on the DB primary key handling?

Comment: Also this (or using 'Contains') give me the exception: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Car'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: Well such a check is in most scenarios very quick, you might consider doing a bulk check like @Ryan suggests. Regarding the error - you can use the identifier in the test.

Comment: You mean identifier as the column name? I have 6 primary keys, why isn't it possible to check like this? (do I have to change my c# objects?)

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but since I came across this post, `->` should be `=>`